# Is there a better way to get the current date in the ISO 8601 format using moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I trying to get the current date in the ISO 8601 format using moment.js.

Is there a better way than the following?

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I feel there should be a better way because here I'm specifying the ISO8601 format explicitly.

The following works too but it feels wrong, too.

```
moment().toISOString().substring(0, 10)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `MomentJs`  library is now deprecated you should think using other libs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert to ISO 8601 dates often, you can create a custom function like this:

```js
moment.fn.formDateISO = function() {
  return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
};

console.log(moment().formDateISO());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Remember that if you are starting a new project, you should not use Moment, as even the official [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) advises against it. A good alternative may be DayJs, which is very similar to Moment.